# ld cannot find print_insn_big_mips(and few others) despite binutils-multiarch-dev installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linker, multiarch

I am trying to compile a program(on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit) that requires binutils with multiarch support(recommended version 2.20).
I have installed `binutils-multiarch 2.24` and the dev package from the distro repository.

However, ld fails to find few functions(print_insn_big_arm, print_insn_big_mips, print_insn_little_arm and print_insn_little_mips).

I suppose either there is a version mismatch or the exact SO files are not found correctly. The flag "-L/usr/lib" is passed to g++ and /usr/lib is where the files installed by binutils-multiarch-dev reside so I'm confused what exactly is the problem.

Has someone faced such issues when using binutils-multiarch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So everything was correctly installed. It turns out that the program expected libopcodes.so to be symlinked to the multi-arch version and not the regular version. Correcting the symlinks fixed the issue.